# Assertion failed (anchor.inside(Rect(0,0,ksize.width,ksize.height))) in cv::normalizeAnchor) when using custom anchorPoint in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

i 'm trying to use filter2D function. There is no error when i use anchor point from -1 to 2 (e.g Point(1,-1), Point(0,0), Point(1,2)...). But when i try to input anchor point at bottom right of kernel matrix (Point(2,-2)) and i get error. Can u guys help me. Thank you.

```
   #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
   #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<math.h>
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace cv;
   using namespace std;
   
   
   int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
   {
       float data1[4][4] = { 1,2,3,3,8,1,10,11,15,16,9,18,1,23,24,25 };
       Mat input = Mat(4, 4, CV_32F, data1);
       cout << "Original Matrix = " << endl << "" << input << endl << endl;
   
       float data2[3][3] = { 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 };
       Mat kernel = Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, data2);
       cout << "Kernel = " << endl << "" << kernel << endl << endl;
   
       Mat output;
       Mat output1;
       filter2D(input, output, input.depth(), kernel, Point(2,-2), 0, 0);
       //filter2D(input, output1, input.depth(), kernel, Point(1,-1), 0, 0);
       cout << "Output Matrix = " << endl << "" << output << endl << endl;
       //cout << "Output Matrix1 = " << endl << "" << output1 << endl << endl;
       waitKey(1);
       cin.get();
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: -2 is not a valid index. -1 means automatic calculation. values 0..(width-1) or 0..(height-1) put the anchor at that position explicitly. would you like me to turn that into an answer?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. But why -2 is not a valid index, when i learnt Opencv i was taught that the top right of 3x3 matrix have an index (0,0) and bottom left is (0,-2). So i want the anchor point at the bottom right which is (2,-2) is it correct ??

Comment: wrong. who taught you that? the issue are the *signs*.

Comment: can you explain more about the sign for me ? please.

Comment: I must insist that you explain who taught you this, or where you have this faulty information from. there is nothing to explain. the anchor must be inside the rectangle. that is a simple and obvious requirement. why do you think negative values make any sense?

Comment: Sorry maybe that my fault for misunderstanding. Because i thought top left is (0,0) and the center  is (1,-1). So by myself i assume that bottom right will be (2,-2).

Comment: no. top left is (0,0). top right is (something, 0), bottom left is (0, something). (-1,-1) is a special value that tells the API to calculate the center on its own. I said this already, and it is explained in the documentation of OpenCV.

Comment: Okay i get it. Thank you for your help! i really appreciate